# Middleware/Inteceptor for HttpSerive in Angular2+

Tags: angular, http, architecture, middleware, interceptor

I have HTTPService which use HttpClient to execute my requests. In one of module of my application I need to declare special headers for group of http operations.

I want to Inherit from HttpService and Create a HttpService and then prepare a new method to set my custom headers, and add it to every request.
But how to do it properly? Is there any native solution to set headers for every request on the top level on HttpService? Or should I override all methods (get, post, etc.) and then add a header for every of them?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: see also https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses